# How does Telnet work?

Tags: objective-c, networking

**Is telnet just a simple socket connection?**

I usually have a difficult time in the networking area so I use some code from the internet to help me out, but I can't seem to find a library for Telnet in Objective-C.

The closest thing I've found is `CocoaAsyncSocket`

I was wondering, *Is telnet just plain socket connections?*

*Do I just create a socket to the server and send the commands?*

Comment: RFC [854](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854) and [855](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc855) are probably two of the key ones, but you likely need to read [all the RFCs on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Related_RFCs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telnet is a bit more than just plain socket connections, but in many cases, just opening a socket to the server and sending the commands will do the trick anyway.

See the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) for more details and links to the RFCs.